# wget. передача URL в кавычках

Tags: linux, wget

Пытаюсь выполнить такую команду:

```sh
wget -c -r -l10 -k -nd -e robots=off 'https://mobile.olimpoks.ru/!/scorms.ecp/865/%d0%9f%d0%91%d0%9f%201101.9_1/index.html'
```

В итоге скачивается только пустой файл *index.html*.

Все потому, что `wget` идет на такой URL:

Tо есть, с кавычкой в конце.

Если передавать URL не оборачивая его в кавычки, тогда получаю такой ответ:

```
-bash: !/scorms.ecp/865/: event not found
```

Как обойти это?

---

UPDATE: На сервере с Cent OS 7 такого результат не дает, а на Ubuntu - такой результат, как описано выше.

Comment: Ваш пример не даёт такого результата.

Comment: @AlexeyTen забыл сказать. на сервере Cent OS 7 такого результат не дает. А на Ubuntu - такой результат как описано в вопросе

Comment: Используй двойные кавычки, всегда нормально работало

Comment: @eri с двойными кавычками ловлю ответ: `-bash: !/scorms.ecp/865/: event not found`

Comment: Экранировать `! ` мне кажется проще тогда

Comment: @eri можете привести пример? пожалуйста

Comment: не воспроизводится. что-то у вас там не так то ли с символами кавычек, то ли со всеми этими опциями, которые вы пытаетесь всучить wget-у. // `wget -S --spider 'https://mobile.olimpoks.ru/!/scorms.ecp/865/%d0%9f%d0%91%d0%9f%201101.9_1/index.html'`  во всех опробованных дистрибутивах получает от сервера ответ про явно непустой файл: `Content-Length: 56894`

Answer (score 1):

Экранируйте `!` через `\!`

```
wget -c -r -l10 -k -nd -e robots=off "https://mobile.olimpoks.ru/\!/scorms.ecp/865/%d0%9f%d0%91%d0%9f%201101.9_1/index.html"
```

Comment: На самом деле не так. Это частный случай и ответ строго под него. А надо просто переконвертировать с преобразованием в HTML кодирование, то есть заменять `!` на `%21`. По-моему `iconv` это умеет делать.

Comment: @0andriy у меня пароль на rdesktop с ! - никакие кавычки не спасают

Comment: Я не понял причём тут пароли на rdesktop.

Comment: такая же проблема была, но вот сейчас что-то обновилось - не воспроизводится теперь